# Why doesn't the menu background color change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have created `2 menus:prod & prod2`, I find when the `mouse focus on prod2`, the background color is changed but when the mouse focus on `prod1 the background color doesn't change`.

**Why it doesn't change?**

**Styles:**

```
ul.hMenu  { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 1;                 
}
ul.hMenu > li  {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width:140px;
}
ul.hMenu li a { 
    display: block; 
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none
}          
ul.hMenu li > div  {                    
    position: absolute;             
    display: none;                
}
ul.hMenu div a {background: yellow;     
}           

div.lay1{ float:left;}  
div.lay1 br{line-height:50%}
.topMenu{font:bold 12px arial;color:#169e39;text-decoration: none;}
.secondMenu{font:12px arial;color:#000000;text-decoration: none;}
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(149, 213, 53, 0);
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-width: 13px;
    left: 10%;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 19px;
    left: 10%;
    margin-left: -19px;
}
```

**Script:**

```
function showMenu(obj){             
    var a=obj.children[0];
    a.style.color="blue";
    var div = obj.children[1];
    obj.style.backgroundColor="yellow";


    div.style.display="block";  

}
function hideMenu(obj){
    var a=obj.children[0];
    a.style.color="red";
    var div = obj.children[1];          
    div.style.display="none";
    obj.style.backgroundColor="";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="hMenu">          
    <li  onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);">
        <a style="color: red;" href="javascript:void(0);">prod</a>              
        <div><br/> 
            <!-- here-->
            <div class="arrow_box" >  
                <div class="lay1">
                   <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a></div>
                   <br><br>
                   <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>     
    <li onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);">
        <a style="color: red;" href="javascript:void(0);">prod2</a>
        <div  class="arrow_box">                                               
            <div  class="lay1">
                <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Help </a></div>
                <br><br>
                <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>  
</ul>   
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
Test
```

[Problem In JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5XJ/)

Comment: Can you make a JSFIDDLE here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it worked! what is your browser? please place a demo and also add this code as well

```
a.setAttribute('style','background-color:blue');
```

some browsers have incompatibility with `element.style`

Answer (score 0):

give CSS Like this

```
.arrow_box{ position:absolute; white-space:nowrap}
```

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/zz5XJ/2/

Comment: This is the new menus,I want the menu itmes backgroud color to be "red".http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/4w99b/4/

Answer (score 0):

try the below HTML:

```
            <body>          
                <ul class="hMenu">          
                    <li  onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);">
                        <a style="color: red;" href="javascript:void(0);">prod</a>              
                             <div class="arrow_box" >  
                                <div class="lay1">
                                   <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a></div>
                                   <br><br>
                                   <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </li>     
                    <li onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);">
                        <a style="color: red;" href="javascript:void(0);">prod2</a>
                        <div  class="arrow_box">                                               
                            <div  class="lay1">
                                <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Help </a></div>
                                <br><br>
                                <div><a href=""  class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br><a href=""  class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>  
                </ul>   
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                Test
            </body>
```

Comment: Nothing changed...
I want the menu itmes backgroud color to be "red",also the arrow should not cover the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/4w99b/4

Answer (score -1):

Please check your HTML :

Because you execute same function for both `Pord or Pord2` but the Inner html is different for both `li`. so `function showMenu()` works different for both `Pord or Pord2`:

HTML:

```
<ul class="hMenu">
        <li onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);"><a style="color: red;"
            href="javascript:void(0);">prod</a>           
            <div class="arrow_box">
             <br />
                <div class="lay1">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br>
                        <a href="" class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <a href="" class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br>
                        <a href="" class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li onmouseover="showMenu(this);" onmouseout="hideMenu(this);"><a style="color: red;"
            href="javascript:void(0);">prod2</a>            
            <div class="arrow_box">
            <br />
                <div class="lay1">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" class="topMenu">Manage Content</a><br>
                        <a href="" class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message </a>
                        <br>
                        <a href="" class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Help </a>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <a href="" class="topMenu">Manage Assignment</a><br>
                        <a href="" class="secondMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Inquiry</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5XJ/1/)

**UPDATED**

Put `<br />` before `arrow_box` div for both `li` and some change into Javascript:

```
var div = obj.children[2];
```

Javascript -

```
   function showMenu(obj){ 
                var a=obj.children[0];
                a.style.color="blue";
                var div = obj.children[2];
                obj.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                div.style.display="block";
            }

    function hideMenu(obj){
                var a=obj.children[0];
                a.style.color="red";
                var div = obj.children[2];          
                div.style.display="none";
                obj.style.backgroundColor="";
            }
```

[Updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5XJ/4/)

Comment: I want to add <br/> before arrow,not after the arrow,you can see that the arrow has covered the menus.

Comment: I want the menu back ground color to be "red",